# How to resize items in RecyclerView dynamically?

Tags: android, drag-and-drop, android-recyclerview, touch, adapter

I've got this result using layout, contains 4 items and in the `OnTouch()`
dynamically resizing cells. It's interesting for me, how to make this effect using adapter
[image]